# How to get a specific cluster after region growing using pcl library?

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am trying to segment the input point cloud using surface normal based region growing, following the tutorial here:http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/region_growing_segmentation.php.
I have been able to achieve satisfactory results for my use case and I could also visualize the segments using pcl::PointCloud ::Ptr colored_cloud = reg.getColoredCloud ();

However, I am not able to find a way to extract a particular cluster that contains all points with normals oriented in a particular direction, for example, the cluster which has all the points with point normals along the z-axis. I assume that such an access to the cluster should be possible, please correct me if I am wrong. Also, any alternative methods to get the feature/s of the individual cluster would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these lines (from the tutorial you mention):

```
std::vector <pcl::PointIndices> clusters;
reg.extract (clusters);
```

Each "cluster" is repressented by `pcl::PointIndices`, which is just a wrapper for a `vector<int>` of indices in the input cloud.

Here is a simple example for calculating the mean normal for each cluster:

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f> mean_normals(clusters.size(), Eigen::Vector3f({ 0.,0.,0. }));
for (auto cluster_idx = 0; cluster_idx < clusters.size(); cluster_idx++)
{
    for (auto point_idx: clusters[cluster_idx].indices)
    {
        mean_normals[cluster_idx] += normals->points[point_idx].getNormalVector3fMap();
    }
    mean_normals[cluster_idx].normalize();
}
```

You may also use `pcl::PointIndices` to create a new cloud for each cluster using `pcl::ExtractIndices`, [as in this tutorial](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/extract_indices.php#extract-indices). Short example:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cluster_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>)
pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ> extract;
extract.setInputCloud (cloud);
extract.setIndices (clusters[cluster_idx]);
extract.filter (*cluster_cloud);
```

Comment: Aren't the input arguments for setIndices be a pointer ? and the clusters returned from the  RegionGrowing class were vectors. How did you manage to pass these vectors to ExtractIndices object ? 

I have been trying to extract the individual clusters in the above said process for past some time but was unsuccesful due to the mentioned reason. Do you have any alternative for this ? Thank you.

Comment: You're right - it should've been `extract.setIndices (pcl::PointIndicesConstPtr(clusters[cluster_idx]));`

Answer (score 0):

You gotta convert cluster which is `pcl::PointIndices` to `pcl::PointIndicesConstPtr` to feed it into `extract.setIndices()`. Here is an example:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr desired_object_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ());
pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZRGB> extract;
extract.setInputCloud (cloud);
pcl::PointIndices::Ptr cluster_ptr(new pcl::PointIndices(clusters[cluster_idx]));
extract.setIndices (cluster_ptr);
extract.setNegative (false);
extract.filter(*desired_object_cloud);
```